# How do I define a type whose definition is implicit in the typing?

Tags: agda

Say I want to define the "diagonal of a type":

```
Σ[ x ∈ A ] Σ[ y ∈ A ] x ≡ y
```

In my mind, it should be the type of equality in A. If I try with

```
data Diag (A : Set) : Σ[ x ∈ A ] Σ[ y ∈ A ] x ≡ y
```

It complains that Diag is *"defined but not accompanied by a definition"*. The point is, shouldn't it be already defined?

I suspect behind this doubt there is a big misunderstanding of how types works in Agda. I come from a course in MLTT, and there I can derive something like

[image]

whose canonical elements are of known shape.

Comment: You're just using wrong syntax. Try something like `Diag = \(A : Set) -> Σ[ x ∈ A ] Σ[ y ∈ A ] x ≡ y`.

Comment: It sure works!
Do you know how I can prove something like $x , y , refl$ is in the Diag A? I have trouble writing the type declaration this time

Comment: ```foo : Diag A; foo = x , x , refl```

Comment: So obvious... Thank yoy